# Выделение изображения при наведении текста и наоборот

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть список и есть картинки(фото).

```css
.fl {
  float: left;
}
.fr {
  float: right;
}
h1 {
  color: #6c0092;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 50px;
}
h2 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.list-win {
  width: 332px;
  height: 782px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  padding-top: 44px;
  padding-left: 41px;
}
.list-win li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}
.list-win li:hover {
  color: #ff001f;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.photoWin {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 720px;
  height: 771px;
}
.photoWin img:hover {
  border: 5px solid #ff001f;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-1">
  <div class="list-win fl">
    <li>Stephen Aguilar</li>
    <li>Juan Owens</li>
    <li>James Foster</li>
    <li>Kenneth Welch</li>
    <li>Cheryl Young</li>
    <li>Bruce Hill</li>
    <li>Jean Alexander</li>
    <li>William Howard</li>
    <li>Brian Jenkins</li>
    <li>Christian Harris</li>
    <li>Christina Medina</li>
    <li>Nancy Rivera</li>
    <li>Brian Jenkins</li>
    <li>Christian Harris</li>
    <li>Christina Medina</li>
    <li>Nancy Rivera</li>
  </div>
  <div class="fr">
    <h2>Октябрь</h2>
    <div class="photoWin">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/150/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/150/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Надо сделать так, чтобы когда наводим курсор на имя-1 в списке слева на фото-1 появляется красный бордер и наоборот наводим на фото-2 появляется бордер и подсвечивается имя-2.

[image: сабж]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение на `jquery`. Если знаете чистый `javascript` то не проблема будет перевести.

Итак. Для начала вам в `css` нужно добавить еще правила для активных картинок и ссылок, чтобы не менять свойства скриптом. Т.е. вместо

```
.list-win li:hover {
  color: #ff001f;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.photoWin img:hover {
  border: 5px solid #ff001f;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

будет

```
.list-win li:hover,  .list-win li.active{
  color: #ff001f;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.photoWin img:hover, .photoWin img.active {
  border: 5px solid #ff001f;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Далее, для всех `li` надо добавить аттрибут `data`. Конечно же для каждого уникальный.

```
 <li data-link-id="1">Stephen Aguilar</li>
    <li data-link-id="2">Juan Owens</li>
    <li data-link-id="3">James Foster</li>
... 
// и так далее
```

для всех картинок также добавить `data` ровно с таким же номером, что и элемент `li`, с которым картинка связана

```
<img data-img-id="1" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
      <img data-img-id="2" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
      <img data-img-id="3" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" height="140">
...
// и так далее
```

Прошу заметить, что у `li` атрибут `data-link-id`, а у картинок `data-img-id`. Хотя не принципиально. Главное чтобы номера соответствовали.

Далее код скрипта:

```
// при наведении на пункт li
    $(document).on('mouseover', '.list-win li', function(){
            var id = $(this).data().linkId;
            $('.photoWin img[data-img-id=' + id +']').addClass('active');       
        });
// при наведении на картинку            
        $(document).on('mouseover', '.photoWin img', function(){
            var id = $(this).data().imgId;
            $('.list-win li[data-link-id=' + id +']').addClass('active');       
        });
// сброс css на дефолтный, если мышку убрали с картинки или ссылки      
        $(document).on('mouseout', '.list-win li, .photoWin img', function(){
            $('.photoWin img').removeClass('active');
            $('.list-win li').removeClass('active');
        });
```

Что тут происходит. При наведении на ссылку, берется его атрибут `data`, считывается его номер и картинке с тем же номером добавляется класс `active`
ранее прописанный в css.

Тоже самое с картинками, но в обратную сторону.

Ну и при убирании мышки с элементов - все классы убираются

---

Есть способ попроще, но (!!!) при условии, что все ссылки слева будут расположены ровно в той же последовательности, что и соответствующие им картинки

Comment: К сожалению не завелось, может я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: @kaktyc  Возможно. Я не телепат  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ .  Предположу, что код скрипта поместить в теги `<script>`... Или `jquery` не подключен.Нужна ошибка, которая выдается.  Код 100% рабочий

Comment: блин, ну все вроде проверил... можно с вами как нибудь связаться?

Comment: Что у вас конкретно не получается? Что вы делаете? И какие ошибки при этом показывает консоль? `jquery` подключаете или нет? ...в чате общаются.

Comment: jquery подключил <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>; В консоли: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:87 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
index.html:102 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
main.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).collagePlus is not a function";

Comment: Ошибка как раз потому, что вы и не подключили. Вам об этом и говорят в консоли `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. Перед `ajax.googleapis...` надо ставить два слэша `//`, либо полностью пусть вместе с `https://` ... http://veynik.ru/jquery/connecting-jquery-google/

Comment: Все, заработало, спасибо. только теперь мой li не красный при ховере...

Comment: Вы случаем не удаляли `.list-win li:hover` ?  Потому, что я лишь дописал свойство в css. Не менял. попробуйте `.list-win li:hover` и `.list-win li.active` отдельно написать. Хотя проблемы быть не должно с этим

Comment: Нет конечно. Но он только цвет не меняет, а text-decoration: underline; ставит. Пробовал, не помогло

Comment: Чудеса-а-а. Но такого быть не может, что один параметр стиля применяется, а другой нет. Только если он где-то еще случайно переопределен. Если есть ссылка на сайт - оставьте. С этим вопросом по стилю уже писать не тут. На ваш изначальный вопрос я ответил и код работает.